# Checking if a character is in a word in PHP

Tags: php, regex

In my program basically your only allowed to use words that contain the letters "IOSHZXN"
I'm trying to figure out a way where you can mix up the letters and it will recognize that it matches.
For example, word SHINT does not match since it has a T, but the word SHINX matches because it contains only the a combination of the letters listed (IOSHZXN)

```
<?php

        $word = "IOSHZNX";

        $charactersallowed = "IOSHZXN";

        if (preg_match('/IOSHZXN/', $word)) {
            echo "YES";
        } else {
            echo "NO";
        }



    ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

It matches anything that is **not** one of those letters and returns the opposite:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^IOSHZXN]+/', $word)) {
    echo "YES";
}
```

Also, if you want it to be case-insensitive, you can use:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^IOSHZXN]+/i', $word)) {
    echo "YES";
}
```

- The `[^...]` matches anything that is not defined within the brackets.
- The `+` continues to search through the entire string.
- The `i` makes it not care about if letters are capitalized or not.

Comment: Can you please explain why I need to use the [^ ], also the /i. Would appreciate it :)

Comment: Alright when I type the characters allowed "IOSHZXN" but append a letter that is not allowed like "IOSHZXNT" it still says it matches? Any way around this?

Comment: That was a major help brother. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: You're welcome.  Yea sorry, I added a vital character on the edit.

Comment: And what do you mean by "matches anything that is not defined within the brackets."? I don't really understand.

Comment: If `IEF` is in brackets, it matches anything other than I, E, and F.

Comment: Also, as a side note, I notice you don't seem to accept answers to questions.  This is vital because it allows future users who are looking for the answer to a problem to find the answer fast and easily.

Comment: Ah sorry. Will fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
if (preg_match('/^[IOSHZXN]+$/', $word)) {
```

`^` and `$` make sure the string only the a combination of letters `IOSHZXN`.